# Symfony 4 - Use service in my form (in query_builder)

Tags: php, forms, symfony, service, autowired

in my symfony 4 project, in my form, I would like to use a service to complete a select. So, I did this :

**Form**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options, GroupeValidateursService $groupeValidateursService)
{
    // $groupeValidateursService = $options['groupeValidateursService'];

    $builder
        ->add('defaultGroupeValidateurs', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => GroupeValidateurs::class,
            'label' => "Service par défaut",
            'placeholder' => "Sélectionnez un service",
            'query_builder' => function () use ($groupeValidateursService) {
                return $groupeValidateursService->getNotDefaultGroups();
            },
            'choice_label' => 'nom',
        ]);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => ParametresAdmin::class,
        'groupeValidateursService' => GroupeValidateursService::class,
    ]);
}
```

**Controller:**

```
$formDeleteDefaultGroupe = $this->createForm(DeleteDefaultGroupeType::class, $parametresAdmin, [
            "groupeValidateursService" => $this->groupeValidateursService,
        ]);
```

If I make a dump die in my service function, it's ok, I've an object array like in a query of a repository.

But I've this error :

> Expected argument of type "Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder", "array" given

I think that it has a problem when I'm returning the array from my function service :

```
/**
 * Retourne tous les groupes sauf celui par défaut
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getNotDefaultGroups()
{
    $groupes = $this->repoGroupeValidateurs->findAll();
    $default = $this->getDefaultGroupe();

    $otherGroups = [];

    foreach ($groupes as $groupe) {
        if ($groupe != $default) {
            $otherGroups[] = $groupe;
        }
    }

    return $otherGroups;
}
```

So I don't understand what's wrong

EDIT : I tried like this :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder
        ->add('defaultGroupeValidateurs', ChoiceType::class, [
            'label' => "Service par défaut",
            'placeholder' => "Sélectionnez un service",
            'choices' => $options['groupeValidateursService']->getNotDefaultGroups(),
            'choice_label' => function ($choice, $key, $value) {
                return $value->getNom();
            }
        ]);
}
```

But I've this error :

> Call to a member function getNom() on string

So, I replaced $value->getNom() by $choice->getNom().

But now I've this error :

```
Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer::renderBlock() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Form\FormView, string given

$formDeleteDefaultGroupe = $this->createForm(DeleteDefaultGroupeType::class, $parametresAdmin, [
            "groupeValidateursService" => $this->groupeValidateursService
        ]);
        $formDeleteDefaultGroupe->handleRequest($request);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EntityType requires QueryBuilder in parameters. You are using anonymous function for option 'query_builder' which return array. You must return QueryBuilder instead:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

$builder
    ->add('defaultGroupeValidateurs', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => GroupeValidateurs::class,
        'label' => "Service par défaut",
        'placeholder' => "Sélectionnez un service",
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $entityRepository) {
            return $entityRepository->createQueryBuilder('gv')
                ->where('gv.group != :defaultGroup')
                ->setParameters(['defaultGroup' => 'someDefaultGrupIdentifier']);
        },
        'choice_label' => 'nom',
    ]);
```

Your **second choice** if you really want to use function from your service is to use ChoiceType where you can pass choices as option:

```
$builder->add('defaultGroupeValidateurs', ChoiceType::class, [
    'choices' => $options['groupeValidateursService']->getNotDefaultGroups(),
    'choice_label' => function ($choice, $key, $value) {
        return $value->getTitle()
    }
]);
```

More info: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities

More info: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#example-usage